# How to create an array from an ascii file with python

Tags: python, arrays, ascii

I have an ascii file (example.dat):

```
3 5 2 1 3 
4 2 3 4 2
2 1 3
2 1 8 7
```

How do I create the following array using python:

```
A = (3, 5, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 8, 7)
```

Comment: And what problems did you have when you tried to do this?

Comment: That's not an array, it's a tuple.

Comment: `with open('example.dat') as infile: t = tuple(itertools.chain.from_iterable(line.split() for line in infile))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input = """3 5 2 1 3 
4 2 3 4 2
2 1 3
2 1 8 7"""

f = [int(i) for i in input.split()]
A = tuple(f)
```

The value of `A` is now:

```
(3, 5, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 8, 7)
```

Important note: This is not an array, this is a tuple. Also, this will only work (because of the `int(i)`) if all of your input is integers.